# Dictionary key from a nested object list

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have an objects list lstItems (Type - Item)

With nested object list in this example Variants( Type Variant )

I need to create a dictionary that the Key will be the SKU field on the nested object

Example :

Item Object Type

```
       Title 
       Quantity 
       Variants ( List of Variant)
```

Variant Object Type

```
       SKU 
       picture
```

For example The data on the Variants

**Variant 1**

SKU : AAAA

Picture : "Blblb.jpg"

**Variant 2**

SKU : BBBB

Picture : "Blblbsd.jpg"

In a beautiful world, i will be able to do this code and it worked (below )
How can i take all the SKU as keys of the object item

```
   Dictionary<string, Product> identityMap1 
     = lstItems.ToDictionary(item => item.Variants.Select(y => y.SKU).ToList());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, you are looking for `SelectMany` to *flatten* the inner list:

```
var identityMap1 = lstItems
  .SelectMany(item => item
     .Variants
     .Select(inner => new {
        key   = inner.SKU,
        value = inner.Picture //TODO: Put the right value here: is it inner? item?
      }))
  .ToDictionary(item => item.key, item => item.value);
```